# React JS for loop inside rendering

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs, jsx

I'm new to React JS and I'm not sure how to do a for loop to render something a variable number of times. This is my code:

```
<div className="product-selector__products">
    { this.props.products.sort(function(a,b) { return a.ranking - b.ranking }).map((p) => { 

        const className = "product" + ((this.props.selectedProductIds.indexOf(p.id) !== -1) ? " product--selected" : "");
        const descriptionHtml = { __html: p.description };
        const nameHtml = { __html: p.name };

        return (
            <div className={className} key={ p.id } onClick={this.onProductClick.bind(this, p.id)}>

                <div className="product__image">
                    <img src={`/~/media/Bayer CropScience/Country-United-States-Internet/Comparison Tool/img/logos/${p.id}_sm.png`} alt={p.name} />
                </div>
                <div className="product__info">
                    <div className="product__name" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={nameHtml}></div>
                    <div className="product__description" dangerouslySetInnerHTML={descriptionHtml}></div>
                </div>
                <div className="product__message" ref={ p.id }>
                    <div className="product__message-tooltip">Please remove a product<br/>before adding another</div>
                    <div className="product__message-triangle-down"></div>
                </div>
            </div>     
        );  
    }) }

    /* Here I want to render <div className="product product--empty"> </div> a variable number of times*/

</div>
```

It generates a grid of product items, with 4 items per row.

I need to add empty divs onto the end of the last row so that each row has the same number of divs in it.

So if `this.props.products.length == 7` I need 1 empty div, and if I have 5 products I need 3 empty divs, etc.

The script i want is this:

```
let remainder = 4 - (this.props.products.length % 4);
  for (let i = 0; i < remainder; i++){
    return ( <div className="product product--empty"> </div> )
  }
```

I'm not sure how to properly put this into the code-block though.

Comment: Why not to `this.props.products.slice(0, 4).map`?

Comment: Your desired code will always complete just the first run in the loop, as you have a *return* instruction.

Comment: @elmeister would that get the remainder that I need? Could you write a more detailed snippet?

Comment: `this.props.products.slice(-this.props.products.length % 4, this.props.products.length % 4 ? undefined : 0).map(() => <div className="product product--empty"/>)`, maybe it's better to assign `this.props.products.length % 4` to variable first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've just modified a little Your code.

```
renderRemainders() {
  let products = []
  let remainder = 4 - (this.props.products.length % 4)

  for (let i = 0; i < remainder; i++){
    products.push( <div className="product product--empty"> </div> )
  }

  return products
}
```

And just put

```
 { this.renderRemainders() }
```

somewhere in Your 'render' function.

Also, could You say something about why you need to render these empty rows?

Comment: I need them for styling purposes, to keep everything positioned evenly. They're just spacers.

Comment: So how about putting them into some container, and just set static height to that container? :)

Creating 'fake nodes' is basically not so great idea.